# Get ACF field value from product attribute on WooCommerce single product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I have made a field to add to the WooCommerce attributes. I have added a picture below for more clearance.

[image]

I am trying to display the field on the single product page. I have added the following code to the content-single-product.php template file.

```php
$terms = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_merk');
var_dump($terms);

$image = get_field('afbeelding_merk', $terms->taxonomy . '_' . $terms->slug);

// Display the image if it exists
if ($image) {
    echo '<img src="' . $image . '" />';
} else {
    echo "<p>Foto niet gevonden.</p>";
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

I tried multiple ways to retrieve the terms taxonomy and slug. But on multiple ways it says NULL. I have tried searching on the internet and asking chatgpt. I have also tried to change the part "$terms->slug" to "$terms->term_id", but that did not help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated:** There are mistakes in your code. Try the following instead:

```php
$product_id = $product->get_id(); // get the product ID
$taxonomy   = 'pa_merk';
$terms      = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, $taxonomy ); // get the product terms

if ( ! is_wp_error($terms) && ! empty($terms) ) {
    $term = reset($terms); // get the first WP_Term object

    $image = get_field('afbeelding_merk', $taxonomy . '_' . $term->term_id);

    // Display the image if it exists
    if ( ! empty($image) ) {
        echo '<img src="'.isset($image['url']) ? $image['url'] : $image.'" />';
    } else {
        echo "<p>Foto niet gevonden.</p>";
    }
} else {
    echo "<p>Foto niet gevonden.</p>";
}
```

Or the shorter WooCommerce version:

```php
$taxonomy   = 'pa_merk';
$term_name  = $product->get_attribute($taxonomy); // get attribute term name

if ( ! empty($term_name) ) {
    $term  = get_term_by('name', $term_name,  $taxonomy);
    $image = get_field('afbeelding_merk', $taxonomy . '_' . $term->term_id);

    // Display the image if it exists
    if ( ! empty($image) ) {
        $image = ;
        echo '<img src="'.isset($image['url']) ? $image['url'] : $image.'" />';
    } else {
        echo "<p>Foto niet gevonden.</p>";
    }
} else {
    echo "<p>Foto niet gevonden.</p>";
}
```

Both should work

Comment: I added both your codes and they both did not work completly. The $image is still empty. It displays NULL. I have also var_dumped the $taxonomy and $term, those work great!

Comment: I have tried both the updated codes. Unfortunatly the same problem persists. The $image still stays empty.

Comment: My code is correct (see [Get Custom Taxonomy Field Value](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/get-custom-taxonomy-field-value/) near the end of the page)... So the problem is about ACF field name and settings, nothing that I can solve. Try to use the field key instead of the slug. Also, maybe it seems that you are using some multilingual plugin, so the problem is maybe around that.

Comment: Ok, I will look further into it myself. Thanks for the help and time.

Answer (score 0):

According to provided code, to implement required functionality to display ACF plugin custom field of type "image", with return format as "Image Array" in woocommerce template file "content-single-product.php", the following code can be used.

```
$image = '';
$terms = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_merk');
if(!is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms))
{
    foreach($terms as $term)
    {
        $image = get_field('afbeelding_merk', $term->taxonomy . '_' . $term->term_id);
        if($image)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
if (isset($image['url']))
{
    echo '<img src="'.$image['url'].'" />';
} else
{
    echo "<p>Foto niet gevonden.</p>";
}
```

If return format of ACF plugin custom field of type "image" is "Image URL", then, in above code, this line of code:

```
if (isset($image['url']))
{
    echo '<img src="'. $image['url']. '" />';
}
```

should be replaced with this line of code:

```
if ($image)
{
    echo '<img src="'. $image. '" />';
}
```

It can be checked, if this code works.